# showing progress Dialog inside an async method

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous

I want to show progress Dialog inside an async event listener method. Right now, the UI compnent is only visible once the async method is finished executing. Here's my code:

```
async void process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        launchRingProgressDialog();

        var comp = await Start();

    }

public void launchRingProgressDialog()
    {
        Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(Activity, "Processing", "Please wait", true);
            ringProgressDialog.SetCancelable(true);
        });
    }
```

The progress Dialog shows when I call the method `launchRingProgressDialog()`outside the async method, but not while the async method is running. How do I make the async method so it doesn't block the UI component?

**Edit**

As I understand, the async method runs inside the UI thread so RunOnUiThread isn't needed. I've changed my code as below but I'm still facing the same issue.

```
 async void process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(Activity, "Processing", "Please wait", true);

        var comp = await Start();

        ringProgressDialog.Dismiss();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When running UI code in an `async` method that is called from the UI thread (for example UI events like button clicks like the one you have in your code), you don't need to use `RunOnUiThread`. This is because when an `await`ed `Task` completes the method continues on the calling thread, which is the UI thread in this case.

For example, look at the following code which is part of one of my apps that runs successfully with the desired results:

```
private async void ExecuteSearchButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    spinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

    CollectionFeed feed = await CollectionFeed.SearchAsync(searchEditText.Text);

    GenericAdapter<Collection, CollectionViewHolder> adapter = 
            new GenericAdapter<Collection, CollectionViewHolder>(Resource.Layout.CollectionRecyclerViewItem,
                                                                 feed.Results, view => new CollectionViewHolder(view));

    searchResultRecyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}
```

The `spinner` appears on click and disappears when the data is loaded into the `RecyclerView.Adapter` (which also loads successfully).

Your edited method will be

```
public void launchRingProgressDialog()
{
    ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(Activity, "Processing", "Please wait", true, true);
}
```

It uses [this `ProgressDialog` constructor](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.ProgressDialog.Show/p/Android.Content.Context/System.String/System.String/System.Boolean/System.Boolean/) to remove the `SetCancelable` call.

Comment: I understand that the async method is running inside UI thread and I don't need to RunOnUiThread. I'm launching the dialog before the async operation runs and dismissing it after await Task but this doesn't really work. the dialog or any other UI component becomes visible only after the entire async method is finished executing. Maybe I should start a new thread inside the async method and run the async operation inside it?

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba If I modify my code which I posted as an example to include a `ProgressDialog`, it appears and is dismissed at the right time. Is your `async` operation of short duration (<1 second)? If it is, that might be the cause because when an `async` method is called for the first time after application start, Xamarin causes a small pause in the application.

Comment: I have resolved it by by running the async operation inside Task.Run. I have one small issue still to be resolved. I wanted to start a new ProgressDiaglog after the first one is dismissed but the second dialog only shows up once the async method is finished executing. Is this because there is too much activity going on on the UI thread and it blocks other UI operations?

Comment: Are your async methods actually asynchronous (i.e. they have an `await` or return a runnable `Task`) or are they `async` for the sake of being asynchronous? If they really are `async`, nothing should be blocking the UI thread.

Comment: I have 2 async methods, when that is called when the button is pressed, and another that runs a process in a separate thread. You can view my full code from here http://pastie.org/10902657

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba from your code it is crystal clear that you do not know how `async` and `await` work in C#. For a method to run asynchronously, it must return a `Task` *and* be called with `await`. Check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/591586/Asynchronous-Programming-in-Csharp-using-async) for more information.

Comment: Ohh I thought I was doing it right all along. I'll check the article. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba you're welcome. Async/await also took me some time to get used to it, but now that I have, I can't live without it :)

Comment: just one question. How come I'm able to await my async methods if they are not returning a Task. Also Shouldn't I get an error of some kind since the return type of the method is Task and I'm not returning a Task?

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba because your method returns `Task<string>` and is marked `async`. If you look carefully, the compiler or your IDE should show a warning that the method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. If it wasn't marked async, the compiler would return an error saying that the types `string` and `Task<string>` do not match. If the method is marked async, the compiler assumes that it will return a Task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116872/discussion-between-ahmed-mujtaba-and-evil-tak).

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba sure.